# Android button onClick method to go to top of layout

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I've been searching a lot about how to implement the onClick method for a button which allows to go to top of a large (scrollable) layout, but I don't find any documentation. Is there any way for doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code for change position of scroll.

```
scrollView.setScrollY(0);
```

[Check this link for more detail.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setScrollY%28int%29)

Comment: That's super simple !

Comment: The three answers are correct, but I accept this one because it is the one that best suits my needs. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try this `scrollView.scrollTo(View.getTop(),View.getRight());`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);//if you move at the end of the scroll

scrollView.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_UP);//if you move at the middle of the scroll
```